# checkout branch become checkout file

Tags: git, shell

Shell output:

```
Wener@Wener-PC /web/learn/angular/learn/angularjs-book
$ git branch --l
* forAnyOption
  forRawgithub
  master
  myMatser

Wener@Wener-PC /web/learn/angular/learn/angularjs-book
$ git co master
切换到分支 'master'

Wener@Wener-PC /web/learn/angular/learn/angularjs-book
$ git co myMaster
error: pathspec 'myMaster' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Wener@Wener-PC /web/learn/angular/learn/angularjs-book
$ git checkout myMaster
error: pathspec 'myMaster' did not match any file(s) known to git.

$ git --version
git version 1.8.3.4
```

How to change branch directly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name in the list of branches is `myMatser` and you're trying to check out `myMaster`...

In this case, `git checkout myMatser` is what you'll want to do.

Answer (score 2):

typo in

$ git branch --l
* forAnyOption
  forRawgithub
  master
  myMatser

matser != master